# User's Claims Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, wif

There are currently two kinds of sign on. one is through active directory, and i am able to get the user's claims identity.

the second is through custom registration form, even that i can get user's claims infomration using this code below:

```
foreach (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.Claim claim in identity.Claims)
{
    Console.Write("Type: " + claim.type);
}
```

Output:

```
claimtype=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
value=test@mail.com
```

The problem I am having is, I am trying to get values of the custom register claims, then save it to user table, using the below code, however no luck

```
var myemail = identity.Claims.First(c => c.ClaimType == "EmailAddress").Value;
```

Error says:

> "Sequence contains no elements"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim type is

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
```

not the `EmailAddress`. If you don't want to repeat the whole type, use `ClaimTypes.Email`:

```
var myemail = identity.Claims.First(c => c.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.Email).Value
```

Your error says then that there are no claims of type `EmailAddress` which is correct. Then you try to take first element of the empty collection and you get the actual exception.

Comment: Yes I tried that too and nothing displays on the screen as if the entire claim type doesn't exist. this is only an error in the "custom user register form" its as if it doesn't recognize the claim or custom login form are treated differently? are they? the strange thing is, i can see all the claims information when i just loop the entire claims.claim

Comment: @Menew: I have no idea as you haven't provided enough details on this custom form. This answer adresses your particular issue you asked in your question. I guess that if this correct answer leads to other issues you should accept this answer but create yet another question with details about your custom form and how you possibly leak claims there.